# Как перегрузить свою html страничку с параметрами

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

В чем смысл моего вопроса?

Пользователь бродит по сайту. Дальше, он решает зарегится и регистрируется.

Как теперь его перебросить на страничку с которой он ушел на регистрацию?

Хоть, намек дайте. А то,я уж кучу и-нета перелопатил, request... Даже вопрос толком задать не получается.

Linux Mint, Python3 и никаких фрэймворков.

Спасибо!
Александр

Comment: намёк: адрес страницы берёте из [http-заголовка referer](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) и сохраняете, например, в cookies-ах. а после удачной аутентификации извлекаете оттуда, куда сохранили, и [отправляете клиента по этому адресу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

Comment: Судя по вопросу, перебрасывать на конкретную страницу вы умеете, данные формы передавать тоже. Можно вместе с регистрационными данными передать и URL для возврата.

Comment: Опять не понял. Ну, что-то не пробивает...
На php это была одна строчка: Header("Location: ".INDEX_SELF.$ref)
Всё! Моя страничка перезапустилась с параметрами.
Как в Питоне?